# How can I send a POST request to Discord Webhooks C#

Tags: c#, discord, webhooks

So I'm making a FiveM resource, that gets a message and then sends it to Discord channel. I'm need it to be server-sided script.

I've tried using WebClient, Flurl.Http and some async, await stuff, but none of them work

I have tried this WebClient

```
using (var wb = new WebClient())
             {
                 string content = message;
                 string username = "" + name + "(ID: )" + id;

                 var data = new NameValueCollection();
                 data["username"] = username;
                 data["content"] = content;

                 var response = wb.UploadValues(discordURL, "POST", data);
                 string responseInString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
                 Debug.WriteLine(responseInString);
             }
```

I have tried using the async, await with Dictionary

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
               { "username", name + " ID: " + id },
               { "content", message }
            };

            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

            var response = await client.PostAsync(discordURL, content);

            var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

And for the final time, I have tried using Flurl.Http

```
var responseString = await discordURL
            .PostUrlEncodedAsync(new { username = name + " ID: " + id, content = message })
            .ReceiveString();
```

Flurl.Http when using returns, that the dependency can't be found and the others just lag the entire FiveM chat resource and doesn't do anything.

If you could help me, it would be the best, thank you.

Comment: When making web requests in C# my preferred library is http://restsharp.org

Comment: You'll have to be more specific than "doesn't work". That could mean almost anything. What actually goes wrong, specifically?

Comment: It seems to have been sandboxed by Cfx. I ended up creating a server-side Lua script with an event handler that calls the PerformHttpRequest Cfx native (as per Benjamin's answer), and in my C# code I have a LogToDiscordWebhook public static method that triggers that event.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to send a message from your FiveM server to your discord web-hook try this native function.

```
PerformHttpRequest('discord web-hook link', function(Error, Content, Head) end, 'POST', json.encode({username = 'bot user name', content = 'message'}), { ['Content-Type'] = 'application/json' })
```

Comment: That's Lua, the question is about C#.